# How do I format values in my lua table to be: t = {['foo'] = true, ['bar'] = true}?

Tags: dictionary, lua, key-value, lua-table, key-pair

This is in relation to a previous question: [Checking values across multiple location and returning a match only if the sources are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697233/checking-values-across-multiple-location-and-returning-a-match-only-if-the-sourc).

Essentially, the function relys on the data being in the format:

```
local vendors = {
                 Asda = {Kellogg = true, Cadbury = true, Nestle = true, Johnsons = true, Pampers = true, Simple = true}, 
                 Tesco = {Kellogg = true, Cadbury = true, Nestle = true, Johnsons = true},
                 Spar ={Nestle = true, Johnsons = true, Pampers = true, Simple = true}
               }
```

However, I am collecting the data by cycling through path locations and adding them into a table, which just creates a list such as:

```
Asda = {"Kellogg", "Cadbury", "Nestle", "Johnsons", "Pampers", "Simple"}
```

There is another way I can add them:

```
local Asda = {}
for index = 1, 9 do 
local pathAsda = factReference -- some path location which changes by index increasing
if pathAsda ~= "" then
    Asda[#Asda+1] = {[Asda] = true} -- table.insert(Asda, pathAsda), for the previously mentioned format
end
```

Which would leave me with:

```
 Asda= {{Kellogg = true}, {Cadbury = true}, {Nestle = true}, {Johnsons = true}, {Pampers = true}, {Simple = true}}
```

I'd then use:

```
table.insert(vendorSources,Asda)
```

Neither of these formats work with the function in the answer and I can't seem to figure out how to amend any section to enable this to work.

```
function intersection(s1, s2) -- finds out if two sets (s1 & s2) overlap
local output = {}

  for key in pairs(s1) do
    output[#output + 1] = s2[key]
  end
return output
end
```

**Is there a way to edit either list (Asda) to be in the correct format?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use `Asda[pathAsda] = true` instead of `Asda[#Asda+1] = {[pathAsda] = true}`, but keep in mind that the order elements is not guaranteed in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, you know when you've been looking at a function too long...seems so obvious though! Order not an issue for this problem